# Joining multiple ifs in 1 statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Will the below result be equivalent to joining the following if conditions

```
if (now_time > time(19,00) and now_time < time(7,00)):
else if (now_time > time(9,50) and now_time < time(12,00)):
else if (now_time > time(14,30) and now_time < time(16,15)):
```

Result

```
if ((now_time > time(19,00) and now_time < time(7,00)) or
    (now_time > time(9,50) and now_time < time(12,00)) or
    (now_time > time(14,30) and now_time < time(16,15))):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `if` and `elif` cases run the same code, yes, but you could also have:

```
if (time(19, 00) < now_time < time(7, 00) or 
    time(9, 50) < now_time < time(12, 00) or
    time(14, 30) < now_time < time(16, 15)):
```

Or even something like:

```
if any(time(*start) < now_time < time(*end)
       for start, end in [((19, 0), (7, 0)), ...]):
```

which allows you to more easily add and remove cases.

Comment: can it really be >19 and <7 at the same time?

Comment: Not in numerical terms, but it depends what the OP's `time`s are.

Comment: why am i getting TypeError: 'module' object is not callable, i am using now = datetime.now()
                            now_time = now.time()
                            if time(19, 00) < now_time < time(23, 59) or time(0, 00) < now_time < time(7, 00) or  time(9, 50) < now_time < time(12, 00) or time(14, 30) < now_time < time(16, 15):

Comment: Do you also have `import time`? Do you mean `datetime.time(...)`?

Comment: i have from datetime import datetime, date, time
import time

Comment: So you have shadowed the class `datetime.time` with the module `time` - why? If you want shorter names, try e.g. `import datetime as dt` and `dt.time(...)`. One name can't refer to two different things - whichever was assigned last will be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this: `if start < now < end:`

Your two examples are not equivalent, as you're now combining all cases into one.